# How to add & compare two times using php

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I want to compare two times.
But first i would like to count up one time for 110 minutes.
What did i do wrong?

Code:

```
$current_time = date("H:i");
$match_start   = strtotime("H:i", "19:30"); // <- Value from database
$match_end     = strtotime("+110 minutes", $match_start)

if($current_time > $match_start && $current_time < $match_end) {

//Match has started

}
```

Comment: Have you even read the [strtotime docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)? The second argument should be a timestamp, not a string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `strtotime()`

```
$current_time = strtotime(date("H:i")); // or strtotime(now);
$match_start  = strtotime("14:30");
$match_end    = strtotime("+110 minutes", $match_start);

if($current_time > $match_start && $current_time < $match_end) {
    echo "Match has started";
}
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/z9Fug4)

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do with the fact that you are comparing strings, not actual time values. Try using `DateTime()` which makes this clearer.

```
$current_time = new DateTime();
$match_start  = new DateTime("19:30");
$match_end    = (new DateTime("19:30"))->modify("+110 minutes");

if($current_time > $match_start && $current_time < $match_end) {

//Match has started

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create datetime like this (change your datetimezone):

```
$match_start   = "19:30"; // <- Value from database
$current_time = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));

$start = new DateTime($match_start, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
$end = new DateTime($match_start, new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
```

Then add 110 minutes to end time:

```
$end->add(new DateInterval('PT110M'));
```

Finally:

```
if($current_time > $start && $current_time < $end)
{
    //Match has started
}
```